# Why I'm getting build wheel error when installing package on Linux

Tags: linux, gcc, installation, pip, pep517

I am working on installing a repository on my Linux and can't seem to download a package correctly. For background, I am a grad research assistant and my post doc is building a package he wants me to test. It's a new version so it could be the package issue but I am also new to coding and it might just be me/my computer.

I am trying `pip install rsnapsim-ssa-cpp`

I double checked that I have cpp on my computer (which is g++ on linux i gathered) and it is up to date.

It starts working but when it gets to build wheel, it breaks down.

The main error, at end of all the error code is,

```
ERROR: Could not build wheels for rsnapsim-ssa-cpp which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

The full description of error is below

```
(base) bsilagy@ENS12372 ~ $ pip install rsnapsim-ssa-cpp
Collecting rsnapsim-ssa-cpp
  Using cached rsnapsim_ssa_cpp-0.0.12.tar.gz (97 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from rsnapsim-ssa-cpp) (1.20.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Cython>=0.26.0 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from rsnapsim-ssa-cpp) (0.29.21)
Building wheels for collected packages: rsnapsim-ssa-cpp
  Building wheel for rsnapsim-ssa-cpp (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/bsilagy/anaconda3/bin/python /home/bsilagy/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmpyouz1bwc
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ax10ddh9/rsnapsim-ssa-cpp
  Complete output (50 lines):
  Warning: passing language='c++' to cythonize() is deprecated. Instead, put "# distutils: language=c++" in your .pyx or .pxd file(s)
  /home/bsilagy/anaconda3
  Located eigen3/Eigen/Dense:
  ['/home/bsilagy/anaconda3/include', '/home/bsilagy/anaconda3/pkgs/eigen-3.3.7-hfd86e86_0/include']
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  skipping 'ssa_translation_lowmem.cpp' Cython extension (up-to-date)
  building 'ssa_translation_lowmem' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
  gcc -pthread -B /home/bsilagy/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/bsilagy/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -I/tmp/pip-build-env-tq8h27ra/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I. -I/tmp/pip-install-ax10ddh9/rsnapsim-ssa-cpp -I/home/bsilagy/anaconda3/include -I/home/bsilagy/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ssa_translation_c_w_full.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ssa_translation_c_w_full.o -I. -I./Include -I/home/bsilagy/anaconda3/include
  cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
  In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/random:35:0,
                   from ssa_translation_c_w_full.cpp:7:
  /usr/include/c++/5/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
   #error This file requires compiler and library support \
    ^
  ssa_translation_c_w_full.cpp: In function ‘void translationSSA_full(int*, double*, double*, int, double, double, int*, int, int, int, double, int, double*, int*, int, int, int*, int, int*, double*, int*, int, int*, int, int*, int, int*, double, double, double*, int*, int*, int)’:
  ssa_translation_c_w_full.cpp:69:2: error: ‘mt19937_64’ is not a member of ‘std’
    std::mt19937_64 rng;
    ^
  ssa_translation_c_w_full.cpp:74:5: error: ‘rng’ was not declared in this scope
       rng.seed(seed);
       ^
  ssa_translation_c_w_full.cpp:75:2: error: ‘uniform_real_distribution’ is not a member of ‘std’
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> unif(0, 1);
    ^
  ssa_translation_c_w_full.cpp:75:33: error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> unif(0, 1);
                                   ^
  ssa_translation_c_w_full.cpp:138:16: error: ‘unif’ was not declared in this scope
     r1 = unif(rng);
                  ^
  ssa_translation_c_w_full.cpp:141:8: warning: unused variable ‘burst’ [-Wunused-variable]
      int burst = 1;
          ^
  ssa_translation_c_w_full.cpp:139:7: warning: unused variable ‘burst’ [-Wunused-variable]
     int burst = 0; // is the system bursting on or off_type with proprotion to kon / koff
         ^
  ssa_translation_c_w_full.cpp:218:19: error: ‘unif’ was not declared in this scope
        r1 = unif(rng);
                     ^
  ssa_translation_c_w_full.cpp:295:23: error: ‘unif’ was not declared in this scope
           r1 =  unif(rng);
                         ^
  ssa_translation_c_w_full.cpp:127:9: warning: unused variable ‘NR’ [-Wunused-variable]
       int NR = 0;
           ^
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for rsnapsim-ssa-cpp
Failed to build rsnapsim-ssa-cpp
ERROR: Could not build wheels for rsnapsim-ssa-cpp which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Can someone please help/advise?

Comment: What version of gcc are you using? It looks like the author was expecting gcc to have C++11 support by default (no standard flag), but you're using a version of gcc that defaults to an older standard.

Comment: The header pathname indicates that this is gcc 5.something. This is a very outdated compiler. gcc versions are now at least twice larger, numerically, than that.

Comment: gcc version is 5.4.0

Comment: I am trying to reinstall the new version but all the codes I am finding on the internet aren't working for an update. I've tried "sudo apt update", and "sudo apt-get update", "sudo apt-get install reinstall gcc-7" and none are working. I'm getting errors with sudo apt update and it isn't finding the package when I try the reinstall. Any tips?

Comment: Also, it's weirdly saying that my g++ is already up to date.                                                                                base) bsilagy@ENS12372 ~ $ sudo apt-get install g++
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
g++ is already the newest version (4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1).

Comment: I've been able to figure it out. I used code sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-9 g++-9
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-9 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-9. This allowed me to update my gcc and set my computer to the newest version of it. Once I did this I was successfully able to install rsnap-sim-cpp. Thank you guys for your help! I wouldn't have had any clue what to do if you didn't mention that my version was outdated.